# Decrease RabbitMQ queue max priority value

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

Hi Have created a rabbit mq queue using below mentioned in picture, and queue got created with max priority value 10, Now I wants to reduce it to 5, Is there any option to decrease max priority value without deleting queue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOCZU.jpg)